# Can someone please explain how loop will work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

```
for x in s[:].split():
    s = s.replace(x, x.capitalize())
```

I want to know how the for loop will progress and what exactly `s[:]` means and will do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What is `s`? Please [edit] to add. I would assume it's a string but `s[:]` doesn't make sense for a string. As well, what specifically are you confused about with the loop, and what parts do you understand? Please also use a descriptive title. LMK when you do and I'll undo my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `s` is a string, `s[:]` makes a copy of the string, and `split()` splits the string at spaces and returns an array of substrings, the for loop will then iterate over the substrings.

It's actually unnecessary because `split` returns an array, so even the though the `for` loop modifies the original string, the loop iterable isn't reevaluated multiple times, so you don't need to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is very likely to be a string because the `split` is a method in `str` (of course, you can also say that `s` is an instance, which comes from a class that is defined by the user in which also has a split method ...)

Normally `s[:]` is like a slice. The following can help you to understand.

```
s ='abc AB C dd'
print(s)
print(s[:])    # same as s
print(s[:3])   # abc
print(s[4:6])  # AB
print(s[-1])   # d
for x in s[:].split():
    s = s.replace(x, x.capitalize())
print(s)  # Abc Ab C Dd  # Now you know the capitalize is what, right?
```

---

## digression

The following is a digression.

I think your question is very bad,

First, this question is very basic.

second, its subject is not good.

Note that an ideal Stack Overflow question is specific and narrow -- the idea is to be a huge FAQ.

And now, you tell me searching **how the loop will work**? I mean, if you are a programmer who must know how the loop it is.
so when you ask a question, you have to think twice about what the title name can benefit everyone. (not just you only)

I suggest that you can delete this question after you understand it.